# Azure Search not finding words containing search query

Tags: search, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with nutritional information. A search for `burger` does not match `hamburger` or `burgers`.

What is the most appropriate & efficient way to be able to search for these with Azure Search? I can use wildcards to match `burgers` (i.e. `burger*`) but Azure Search does not support wildcards at the start of the query, so I can't figure out how to match `hamburger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Lucene query syntax (see link below) in azure search.

Construct your query by using querytype full (which enables Lucene query syntax) with your term as a search. As an example, to find all matches containing the word burger, construct your query like this (try it in the azure search, search explorer query window:

```
queryType=full&search=/.*burger.*/
```

[Microsoft docs for Lucene query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_regex)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work - I still get no results. Tried in both code and Azure Management portal.

Comment: Strange @Sam, are all the desired columns marked as 'Searchable' in your index, and have the indexer run successfully?

Comment: Sorry for taking a month to come back to you, just revisited this now. Turns out I missed the queryType=full part of the query :). Thanks for your help.